# PHP - Array and loops for

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I need help, I am at a loss to understand what about array and loops "for". I have to display the column on the right cell.

The answer of my query. note, I have 13 array like this:

```
print_r ($toto) = 

Array ( [0] => 

   Array ( [id_depot] => 21758777 
           [code_stp] => CHI 
           [date_depot_const] => 20/11/18 
           [date_depot_decla] => 
           [num_bip] => 0100514871
           [num_depot] => AB421743 
           [typ_depot] => 51004 
           [typ_declaration] => )
```

My html:

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 <th>ID_DEPOT</th>
 <th>CODE_STP</th> 
 <th>DATE_DEPOT_CONST</th>
 <th>DATE_DEPOT_DECLA</th>
 <th>NUM_BIP</th>
 <th>NUM_DEPOT</th>
 <th>TYP_DEPOT</th>
 <th>TYP_DECLARATION</th>
 </tr>
<?php 
 $i = 0;
 for ($i=0 ;$i <= count($this->toto);$i++){
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>'.$this->toto['id_depot'].'</td>';
 echo '<td>'.$this->toto['code_stp'].'</td>';
 echo '<td>'.$this->toto['date_depot_const'].'</td>';
 echo '<td>Jill</td>';
 echo '<td>Smith</td>';
 echo '<td>50</td>';
 echo '<td>Jill</td>';
 echo '<td>Smith</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
 }   
?>
```

Of course i have to fill all the column but currently I fill only 3 for the example

The answer :

[image]

My first three column are empty and I don't know why :( it should display my array... Do you have an idea?

Comment: echo '<td>'.$this->toto[$i]['id_depot'].'</td>';

Comment: If you have an array of arrays, may I ask why using `for` instead of `foreach`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using the index.

```
$this->toto['id_depot']
```

Should be

```
$this->toto[$i]['id_depot']
```

And you need to fix the for loop, `<=` should be only `<`:

```
 for ($i=0 ;$i < count($this->toto);$i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays are in an array... you need to use `[$i]` as it is the first array with an index of [0] that you are displaying to target that array, then the `key` you require:

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <th>ID_DEPOT</th>
 <th>CODE_STP</th> 
 <th>DATE_DEPOT_CONST</th>
 <th>DATE_DEPOT_DECLA</th>
 <th>NUM_BIP</th>
 <th>NUM_DEPOT</th>
 <th>TYP_DEPOT</th>
 <th>TYP_DECLARATION</th>
 </tr>
<?php 
 $i = 0;
 for ($i=0 ;$i <= count($this->toto);$i++){
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>'.$this->toto[$i]['id_depot'].'</td>';
 echo '<td>'.$this->toto[$i]['code_stp'].'</td>';
 echo '<td>'.$this->toto[$i]['date_depot_const'].'</td>';
 echo '<td>Jill</td>';
 echo '<td>Smith</td>';
 echo '<td>50</td>';
 echo '<td>Jill</td>';
 echo '<td>Smith</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
 }   
?>
```

As you start your loop from zero, you don't need to count all the way up to your array count as that would be one to many.

Answer (score 1):

I understand there is an answer, just though of providing a different approach :)

```
foreach ($this->toto as $key => $toto) {
     echo sprintf(
             '<tr><td>%d</td>%s<td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%d</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',
               $toto['id_depot'],
               $toto['code_stp'],
               $toto['date_depot_const'],
               `Jill`,
               `Smith`,
               50,
               `Jill`,
               `Smith`
          );
 }
```

Think the example above will save you headaches and organize your script a bit more :)
For the remaining hard-coded examples you have, all you need is to replace for the correct `sprintf` value and target the desired `key` from your `array`